# Portmanteau test results R

Tags: autocorrelation, vector-autoregression

When reading a VAR model tutorial I was confused by the below excerpt on the Portmanteau test for autocorrelation.

My questions are:

1) How does one interpret the results of the below demonstration?

2) How does the author come to the conclusion that the VAR(3) model is more suitable, and based on what criteria?

3) Assuming (I don't know if it is the right assumption) that autocorrelation is a desired trait in terms of VAR($p$) predictions, why does the author move on to VAR(3) after rejecting the null hypothesis for VAR(1)?

```
> #vector autoregression with lag1
> var = VAR(climate2.ts, p=1)

#It is important now to test for serial autocorrelation in the model      
#residuals and below is for the Portmanteau test (several options in the vars 
#package are available).

> serial.test(var, lags.pt=10, type=”PT.asymptotic”)

Portmanteau Test (asymptotic)

data:  Residuals of VAR object var
Chi-squared = 55.4989, df = 36, p-value = 0.01996

#The null hypothesis is no serial correlation, so we can reject it with extreme 
#prejudice…on to var3
> var3 = VAR(climate2.ts, p=3)
> serial.test(var3, lags.pt=10, type=”PT.asymptotic”)

Portmanteau Test (asymptotic)
data:  Residuals of VAR object var3
Chi-squared = 36.1256, df = 28, p-value = 0.1394

#That is more like it.  
#You can review the details of the var model, in this case temperature, if you so choose:
> summary(var3, equation=”d.temp”)
```

Comment: serial.test(var3, lags.pt=10, type=”PT.asymptotic”), Why did you choose the logs.pt = 10?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let me use the term "autocorrelation" as a synonym for "serial correlation".

> 1) How does one interpret the results of the below demonstration?

Most of the interpretation is already in the comments to the code. First, a VAR(1) model is estimated. It is tested for autocorrelation in errors using a portmanteau test. The null hypothesis of **no** autocorrelation is rejected since the $p$-value of `0.01996` is lower than the significance level of `0.05`. Since autocorrelation is an **un**desirable feature of the model, the author moves on to look for another model that does **not** have autocorrelation. He/She estimates a VAR(3) model, tests for autocorrelation, and finds that the null of **no** autocorrelation **cannot** be rejected because the $p$-value of `0.1394` is greater than the significance level of `0.05`. Since there is not enough evidence of presence of autocorrelation, the author is satisfied and sticks to the VAR(3) model.

> 2) How does the author come to the conclusion that the VAR3 model is more suitable, and based on what criteria?

Lack of autocorrelation makes VAR(3) more suitable than VAR(1); see also my answer to question (1).

> 3) Assuming (I don't know if it the right assumption) that serial autocorrelation is a desired trait in terms of VAR(p) predictions, why does the author move on to var3 after rejecting the null hypothesis for var?

Autocorrelation is **not** a desired trait. It biases the estimators and makes them less efficient. Meanwhile, the estimators do have their nice properties (unbiasedness, efficiency) when there is **no** autocorrelation (assuming the other standard assumptions are satisfied, too).

Comment: I have run similar serial.test. None of the value of p is higher than 0.05, which value of p should be chosen in this case. The p-values are below:

var2: p-value = 0.001724 ||
var3: p-value = 0.0006012 ||
var4: p-value = 0.001473 ||
var5: p-value = 0.02089 ||
var6: p-value = 0.04144 ||
var7: p-value = 0.03206 || 
var8: p-value = 0.004582 || 
var9: p-value = 5.929e-05

Comment: @Ritesh Shinha, maybe you should go back one step and check if your series are stationary. From that same example: ndiffs(co2, alpha = 0.05, test = c(“adf”)) [1] 1 > ndiffs(surfacetemp, alpha = 0.05, test = c(“adf”)) [1] 1 Using the adf test above in the ndiffs command of the forecast package, we can see that a 1st difference will allow us to achieve stationarity, which is necessary for vector autoregression and granger causality I found the example on this link: https://www.r-bloggers.com/an-inconvenient-statistic/